# ScriptManager Error in the application

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have below scenario in my ASP.net using C# application

Master page:

I have included below code in Site.Master to register the scriptmanager as used some Telerik controls in it:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %> 

<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/app.js?v=1" />
            </Scripts>
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

I have a Data.aspx page on which I have a button which opens up a popup which is ShowPopup.aspx

In ShowPopup.aspx I have used Telerik `RadGrid` and also a `UpdatePanel` so included below scriptmanager code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID='scriptManager' runat='server' EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

I haven't included any scriptmanager code on Data.aspx page.

I have another ascx page which is used to set header of every panel. Below is the code we have used for Header.ascx page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ContentHeaderUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="contentHeader">
            <div runat="server" id="PageHeader">Content Title</div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And I haven't included any ScriptManager in this ascx file
We have using this header page in ShhowPopup.aspx page like:

```
<uc:ContentHeader ID="Header" runat="server" Title="Employee Details" />
```

Issue is, when I click on button in Data.aspx page, a popup (ShowPopup.aspx) page should open giving details, but instead it is giving Server Error in application like:

```
The control with ID 'ContentHeaderUpdatePanel' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it
```

proper error description can be found [image: here]

I tried to add ScriptManager control in Header.ascx page but then it gives Error like:

```
Only one instance of scriptmanager can be added to the page
```

I can also see error when I try to see design view of ShowPopup.aspx page:

```
Error Creating Control - EmployeeGrid Failed to create designer 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2013.1.417.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4'
```

One more issue is there.
I have IIS setup at my laptop and also deployed code on server. Error can not be reproduced on the one where IIS is setup. Why is it so?

Comment: see this can help you https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/troubleshooting/general-troubleshooting#error-message-the-control-with-id-controlid-requires-a-scriptmanager-on-the-page-the-scriptmanager-must-appear-before-any-controls-that-need-it

Comment: unfortunately, no. This is not the one I am looking for

Comment: Where did you include the two script managers. And in which order. Try adding them both on masterpage and frist add the Aspnet default one and then the telerik.

Comment: @SehaxX: I tried that as well. It gives me error of Only one instance of scriptmanager can be added to the page

Comment: What happens when zou remove the ScriptManager, only leaving the Telerik one.

Comment: @SehaxX: If you are asking about the scriptmanager on ShowPopup.aspx, when i remove it, it gives me error for the UpdatePanel control which is on Showpopup.aspx page

Comment: So instead of ScriptManager, on pupop. Try to add ScriptManagerProxy. <asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server"></asp:ScriptManagerProxy> and see what happens